# Combining Data within an Excel Sheet

Tags: excel

I'm currently working on an excel document for work, refer to the following link for access to the document: https://www.dropbox.com/s/di23jketed2slc2/VolumebyMethod.xlsx?dl=0.

What I need to be able to do is combine data that appears within the "Combine" tab and have it appear within the "Dashboard" tab.

For example, OntarioLearn (which is listed three times). I'd need a script or formula that would grab the variables to place it on the main "Dashboard".

I'd also need it to change based on volume increase.

Comment: Take the relevant data out of the linked worksheet and post it into your question along with your own effort made towards solving this issue (working or not).

Comment: That's just it, as far as I've been able to get is the following formula:

=INDEX('Chats - February 2017'!$A$2:$A$60,MATCH(1,INDEX(('Chats - February 2017'!$B$2:$B$60=LARGE('Chats - February 2017'!$B$2:$B$60,ROWS(D$2:D2)))*(COUNTIF(D$2:D2,'Chats - February 2017'!$A$2:$A$60)=0),),0))

But this only allots for one area, I'm lost on how to be able to pull off different variables across a bigger amount of data